# Move constructor C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I am looking at some code that I have inherited and it has a matrix class which implements 2D matrices in C++ and has move constructors and assignment operator.

The way it is implemented is as follows:

```
template<typename T, int rows, int cols>
class matrix_data {
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data_;
    // Some definitions
    typedef matrix_data<T, rows, cols> this_type

    matrix_data(this_type && other)
    {
        std::swap(data_, other.data_);
    }
};
```

Now, I am not sure why the data pointers are being swapped here. I thought it should be something like

```
data_ = std::move(other.data_);
```

I am guessing with the swap it is still ok because the `other` instance should be in an invalid state anyway after the move.

My question is whether I can replace the statement with `data_ = std::move(other.data_);` Is there some `unique_ptr` deletion stuff that is the reason for doing the swap instead of the move i.e. if I do the move would the original data be deleted correctly?

Comment: Swapping the objects contents with a known temporary (about to expire) ensures that the object's current data members are cleaned up.  In this case it might not be necessary but it is a common pattern for this operation.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for clarifying that. I was wondering if that was the objective i.e. to ensure that the data is cleaned up. It is weird though in the sense that the deletion almost feels like a side effect...

Comment: It's one less function to change if you add or remove data members from the object.  The destructor will (might)  have to change but the move constructor does not, this makes code changes less error prone.  Also std::swap can usually give the strong exception guarantee, which can then be propagated to the move constructor.

Comment: I think "the other" must be left in a *valid* (but unspecified) state, otherwise its destruction will be broken.

Comment: Best solution, `matrix_data(this_type && other) = default;`. No point in using `std::swap`, it does more work.

Comment: @juanchopanza Would this invoke move on the underlying unique_ptr?

Comment: @Luca yes, which is exactly the right thing to do. In fact, you don't even need to add the move constructor. So, best solution: remove the constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks! I will do some tests just to convince myself ;-)

Comment: If the `...` part of the class contains some other constructors, which is rather likely, you *will* have to specifically ask for a move constructor (but can use the `= default` version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

Yes, you could replace the swapping with

```
data_ = std::move(other.data_);
```

but as the comments suggest, that's happening anyway when you do not implement the move constructor, as long as you do not implement neither a copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move assignment operator or destructor. If you have implemented one of the above, marking the move constructor as `=default` will also do the job.

Swapping the objects' contents is indeed not necessary in this case as there  is actually nothing to swap, because this being a (move) constructor, `this->data_` does not point to any previously allocated memory location that should be freed after the pointer to it has been overwritten.

Therefore swapping is usually done when implementing the move *assignment* *operator*, because in this case `this->data`_ usually holds a pointer to a memory location that needs to be freed sometime. By putting this pointer into the moved-from object, the memory it is pointing to will be freed when the destructor for the moved-from object is called.